# Unreal Engine 4: детекирование столкновения быстро движущихся объектов

Tags: unreal-engine-4

В игре есть два объекта: один небольшой и быстро движущийся. Второй большой но тонкий и медленно движущийся.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Они должны сталкиваться. Траектория быстрого объекта пересекает медленный объект, но быстрый объект проскакивает сквозь медленный между двумя тиками. Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно реализовать детектирование столкновения между двумя этими объектами?

На текущий момент движение быстрого объекта реализовано через ручное добавление к его положению вектора скорости умноженного на время:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Возможно ли при таком способе детектировать столкновения? Какой способ движения оптимален для детектирования столкновений? Быстрый объет должен двигаться равномерно и прямолинейно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно испольовать два варианта:

- Timeline
- ProjectileMovement

**Timeline** - устанавливается из Blueprint'a, вызовом Timeline... . С его помощью, можно добавить кривую, от 0 до 10000 единиц (допустим, что это движение по X)
Установив Timeline, подключаем перемещение Actor в Update, и для установки координат, используем переменную Float.

**ProjectileMovement** - добавляем как компонент к Actor. Это некая эмуляция движения снаряда. Нам достаточно указать в нем Initial Speed, Max Speed - 20000 единиц, и гравитация (ProjectileGravity) - 0.0
Траектория движения - по оси Х.